# try catch начал ловить E_WARNING

Tags: php, symfony

Недавно обнаружил, что в проекте конструкции вида:

```
try {
    // Пример ошибки, которая в php 7.2 вызовет ошибку уровня E_WARNING
    $c = \count(null);
} catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
    // Сработает на E_WARNING: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
}
```

стали реагировать на предупреждения E_WARNING. 
Что этому предшествовало: некоторое время назад была "поднята" версия php до

```
PHP 7.2.7 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2018 02:04:37) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.0alpha2-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.7, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

в ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING
```

и была "поднята" версия symfony до 4.1.0

Это новая фича php или где-то в symfony дополнительный хендлер, который я не нашел?

Comment: Мануал не пробовали открывать http://php.net/count?

Comment: Разумеется. Я поэтому и привел в примере ошибку, которая "count() теперь будет выдавать предупреждение о некорректных исчисляемых типов, переданных в параметр". Вопрос то не в этом. Почему предупреждение срабатывает в try catch.

Comment: В чистом php не кетчится https://3v4l.org/VTmlg, так что может действительно что-то симфоническое.

Comment: @u_mulder да, симфони. Покопался в коде. Ответил на свой вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это все же Symfony. В dev среде создается хендлер обработки ошибок, в котором все ошибки превращаются в фатальные

```
if (!$exception instanceof \Exception) {
    $exception = new FatalThrowableError($exception);
}
```

поэтому и срабатывает try catch на E_WARNING и E_NOTICE